# Building the same project in Eclipse in different jars depending on a profile

Tags: java, eclipse, build, jar, profile

I keep server and client code in the same project of Eclipse. Libraries for both of them are included. Images for the client are also added to the build path.

Now I want to generate jars for server and client, that they include only required libraries, and server jar does not have images included.

Is there a way to do this without maven, etc?

Comment: I would recommend considering having 3 distinct projects, server, client and any shared components you have. Client and server could then have a dependency on shared library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide your sources into three source (and output) folders within the same project:

- src-shared
- src-server
- src-client

Then create a `build.xml` (Ant buildfile) which creates a jar from `bin-shared` + `bin-server` and a jar from `bin-shared` + `bin-client`.

---

Note: One danger of keeping it in the same project is that you can accidentally use client classes from server classes, or vice versa, which will fail at runtime. To fix this, make three projects instead of three source folders.

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on the project and go to Export.  Select jar from the selection tree and in the next tab, remove the code/resources that you don't want included in the jar.  Better still if you keep them in separate projects (even if there is no client java code, you can create a resource project).

However, what you're describing sounds a lot like a WAR file.  Contrary to a jar, a WAR file is a deployable jar meant to be added to a web hosting application like [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/).  I don't know if that's suitable for your needs, but more often than not, you want to have both server and client code together.  If your project is dependent upon another project, that project will automatically create a jar that will be included in the WAR.

Comment: I have tried before only for Jar Executable File, so there was no a choice there. In just Jar file there is a choice for resources, right. Now I need a way to keep the same configuration for later uses.

Comment: I don't think that's possible solely on profile.  As much of a pain as it might be, I think it would be better to restructure your project as necessary to make it work in all circumstsances, meaning keeping it in a more traditional fashion.